# Android webview does not load a URL in mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to load a url in android app webview but it's failing I don't know what's the exact problem. onPageStared() and method called, onReceiveError method not called, onPageFinished method is also called. Below is my code -

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun setupWebView() {
        webviewViewModel.loadingVisibility.value = View.VISIBLE
        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {

                view?.loadUrl(webviewViewModel.url)
                return true
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                webviewViewModel.loadingVisibility.value = View.GONE
            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl(webviewViewModel.url)
    }
```

and URL I'm using is - `http://192.168.10.22:4200/bigday/terms-and-conditions`

Help me for what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

After 2-3 days search I got the solution by adding

`webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true`

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun setupWebView() {
        webviewViewModel.loadingVisibility.value = View.VISIBLE
        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {

                view?.loadUrl(webviewViewModel.url)
                return true
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                webviewViewModel.loadingVisibility.value = View.GONE
            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl(webviewViewModel.url)
    }
```